# C# - Clear selected calendar date if it is the same

Tags: c#, datepicker, calendar

I have a calendar in my C# code and I want for a date to be deselected if I click on the same date. How to do that?

```
protected void SelectionChangeCalendar(Object sender, EventArgs e){

   selected_date = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();

   if(same date is clicked){
      Calendar1.SelectedDates.Clear();
   }

}
```

The problem here is that I believe if the same date is chosen "SelectionChangeCalendar" is not fired.

Markup:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="SelectionChangeCalendar"></asp:Calendar>
```

Comment: Why not have a button next to the calendar control that clears the selection, its not very intuitive to clear the calendar value when the same date is selected.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Added markup

**EDIT:** Included fix from yazanpro

You are correct that if you click on the already selected date the OnSelectionChanged event does not fire.  It does, however, post back with the event target and event argument just like it would if it were a different date, so you can check for the form arguments and then go from there.  The trick was that if you check on page load and then clear the selected date, you end up triggering the OnSelectionChanged event and the date just gets selected again.  But if you wait until after the Calender has processed the post back data and decided there was no change, you can successfully clear the date.  Here's the code I used to get it to work:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    bool clear = true;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if we are here, the date actually changed, so set clear to false
        clear = false;
    }

    protected void Calendar1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if clear is true and the event target is the calendar and a date was clicked
        if (clear  
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"])
            && Request["__EVENTTARGET"].Contains(Calendar1.ID)
            && char.IsDigit(Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"][0]))
        {
            Calendar1.SelectedDates.Clear(); //clear the date
        }
    }

}
```

**Markup:**

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnPreRender="Calendar1_PreRender" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>
```

The clear variable just keeps track of whether or not the date was actually changed.  If it was, the OnSelectionChanged event will fire and we know that we don't have to clear any dates.  Here are the steps:

1) When the page posts back, if the event target was the Calendar, the Calendar checks the post data to see if the selection has changed.  If it has, it calls the event handler and we set `clear = false`, meaning we know that a different date was clicked on. If the selection hasn't changed, the Calendar won't fire the even and clear remains true.

2) After the events have been handled, we use the prerender event to check if the event target was the calendar.  If it was, and clear is still true, then we know that either the selected date or one of the calendar controls was clicked on.  As it turns out, if a control is clicked on, the event argument starts with a letter.  If a date was clicked on, it starts with a number (the argument is the number of days since Jan 1, 2000). So all we have to do is check if the first character of the event argument is a digit to see if the currently selected date was clicked on.  If so, we clear the date and we're done.

I don't know, it works, but it smells.  Maybe there's a better way to do it?  It seems though that the Calendar control was not designed to work this way.  Anyway, I hope this helps!

Comment: Remember that having master pages would make your condition unmet since Calendar1 ID will be different than "Calendar1". It better gets replaced with:
`if (clear
                && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]) && Request["__EVENTTARGET"].Contains(Calendar1.ID)
                && char.IsDigit(Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"][0]))`

Comment: How does Calendar1_PreRender get fired? I did as you explained but it is not clearing and it seems it is not firing up. Anything I should include in the Markup?

Comment: Include `OnPreRender = "Calendar1_PreRender"` in the grid markup

Comment: yazanpro got it.  I've added it to the answer.

Comment: I will test it soon and I will let you know if it works. Thanks for everything so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Check if selected Date is in the saved list
            // Remove the Selected Date from the saved list
            if (SelectedDates.Contains(Calendar1.SelectedDate))
                SelectedDates.Remove(Calendar1.SelectedDate);
            else
                SelectedDates.Add(Calendar1.SelectedDate);
            ViewState["Dates"] = SelectedDates;
        }
```